# Magento 2.0 with MySQL 5.5

Tags: magento2, mysql, install

Is MySQL 5.6 mandatory for Magento 2.0 or will it work with MySQL 5.5 itself? 

If so, how to skip the mysql detection step?

P.S. My hosting provider supports only MySQL 5.5

Comment: Please let us know if you are able to install Magento using proposed hack.

Comment: I tried your method and skipped the mysql detection step, but unfortunately can't install it..

Comment: It was expected since 5.5 it is not supported.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Magento 2 use InnoDb Fulltext Indexes and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP default value that not available in Mysql 5.5. So you cannot install it and skip detection step cannot help you.

Answer (score 1):

You will need 5.6 for Magento 2. This shouldn't be a problem as most specialist Magento hosts will support shared hosting with MySQL 5.6

Answer (score 0):

Magento 2 need mysql 5.6, you should review your hosting services before you buy it. still you can request at support to upgrade the hosting.

You can also use some third party mysql services which can be integrated with your current hosting package. They offer few limited space for free or can buy some mysql space.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL 5.6 is now EOL you should hopefully now be using PHP 7.4 with Magento 2 and in our opinion MySQL 8 or MariaDB 10.3

Answer (score -1):

The only supported MySQL version for now is 5.6.

If you want to experiment by suppressing this check, go to

```
 \Magento\Setup\Controller\DatabaseCheck::indexAction()
```

and add at the beginning of the method

```
return new JsonModel(['success' => true]);
```

Comment: see @KAndy's reply in regards to suppressing the check